# Large dataframe self-join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, self-join, apache-spark-dataset

Consider a large dataframe (~ 800 GB, 300 million rows)

```
+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+
|C1 | C2  |C3 | C4  |C5 | C6  |
+---+-----+---+-----+---+-----+
```

I want to join a the dataframe to itself (by columns C1 and C2)

```scala
val srcDF = spark.read.orc("...")
val secondDF = srcDF.select(
        'C1 as "C1_t",
        'C2 as "C2_t",
        'C3 as "C3_t",
        'C4 as "C4_t", 
        'C5 as "C5_t",
        'C6 as "C6_t"
      )

val resultDF = srcDF.join(secondDF, srcDF("C1") === secondDF("C1_t") && srcDF("C2") === secondDF("C2_t"))
```

I've got an error "has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle"

I've tried bucketBy and partition by columns (C1, C2), nothing helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why join a table by itself? Did you want to dk something that could be accomplished by a group by?

Comment: @JasonChia, i didn't. I have to join by itself. for example, i need a C5 and C5_t for some transformations and comparing

Comment: Could you check if your worker nodes have enough space? The assigned memory, size of single partition etc. Some documentation on that exception related to swap memory space. Do include your spark setup if possible.